# how to append Search bar in custom table view programatically

Tags: ios, xcode, uitableview

I have implemented the table view using custom table view cell. 
 I want to put the search bar in table view.

Can someone tell me how i can programmatically append one such search bar.
please try not to provide external links. thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
UISearchBar *tempSearchBar = [[UISearchBar alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, self.tableView.frame.size.width, 0)];
self.searchBar = tempSearchBar;
[tempSearchBar release];
self.searchBar.delegate = self; 
[self.searchBar sizeToFit];  
self.tableView.tableHeaderView = self.searchBar;
```

hope this help.

Comment: which delegate should we use for search bar??

Comment: and what have you written in CGRectMake(   ??    ). Thanks for quick reply .

Comment: hey i can't find UISearchBar. Which header file should i import?

Comment: add this delegate <UISearchBarDelegate>.and CGRectMake is used to set place of your searchbar in our case i have seted it on top of the table view,and you dont need to add any extra header file its in uikit framework.and sorry for late reply i am at lunch break.